# Laravel5.5 routing; 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to create a contact pop up form in Laravel but seems like the routing is not working. I'm starting from 'contact.blade.php', using 'contact-provider.js'. Browser gives following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/vendor/186/contact 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

contact.blade.php (full) (is inserted into home-extended.blade.php -> see under)

```
<section class="o-container u-mt-x12 u-mb-x12">
    <div class="o-grid">
        <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12">
            <div class="c-card c-card--bigborder u-p-x6 u-mb-x4">
                <div class="o-grid">
                    <div class="o-grid__col u-7/12@lg u-border--contact">
                        <h3>@lang('profile.vendorContactTitle')</h3>
                        <div class="o-grid">
                            <div class="o-grid__col u-5/12@md">
                                <p class="u-bold"><span class="u-weight-bold">{{ $profile->user->company_name }}</span><br/>{{$profile->services->pluck("name")->implode(", ")}}</p>
                                    {{ $profile->subtitle }}
                                @if ($profile->address)
                                <p class="p2">
                                    {{ $profile->address->street }} {{ $profile->address->street_no }}<br/>
                                    {{ $profile->address->zip }} {{ $profile->address->city }} | {{$profile->address->country_code}}
                                </p>
                                @endif

                            </div>
                            <div class="o-grid__col u-7/12@md">
                                <table>
                                    @if($profile->phone)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="p2 u-weight-bold u-color-deep-cove-blue u-weight-bold">@lang('profile.vendorContactPhone'):</td>
                                        <td class="p2"><a class="c-link c-link__primary" href="tel:{{ $profile->phone }}">{{ $profile->phone }}</a></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($profile->mobile)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="p2 u-weight-bold u-color-deep-cove-blue">@lang('profile.vendorContactMobile'):</td>
                                        <td class="p2">{{ $profile->mobile }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                     @endif
                                     @if($profile->email && !$profile->user->is_ahuser)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="p2 u-weight-bold u-color-deep-cove-blue">@lang('profile.vendorContactMail'):</td>
                                        <td class="p2"><a href="mailto:{{ $profile->email }}"
                                                          class="c-link c-link__primary">{{ str_limit($profile->email, $limit = 27, $end = '...') }}</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($profile->web)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="p2 u-weight-bold u-color-deep-cove-blue">@lang('profile.vendorContactWeb'):</td>
                                        <td class="p2">
                                        @if(strpos($profile->web, 'http') !== 0)
                                        <a href="http://{{ $profile->web }}" class="c-link c-link__primary" target="_blank">{{ $profile->web }}</a>
                                        @else
                                        <a href="{{ $profile->web }}" class="c-link c-link__primary" target="_blank">{{ $profile->web }}</a>
                                        @endif
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endif
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="o-grid__col u-5/12@lg u-mt-x6 u-mt-x0@lg">
                        <h6>@lang('profile.vendorServicesTitle')</h6>
                        @foreach($profile->services as $service)
                            @foreach ($service->children->whereIn('id', $profile->user->categories->pluck('id')) as $child)
                            <p class="p2 u-weight-bold u-color-gray u-mt-x6 u-mb-x2">{{ $child->name }}</p>
                            <ul class="o-list o-list--inline c-unordered-list--divider p2">
                                @foreach($child->specifications->whereIn('id', $profile->user->specifications->pluck('id')) as $specification)
                                    <li class="o-list__item">{{ $specification->name }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="o-grid">
                    <div class="o-grid__col u-7/12@lg u-border--contact ">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <div class="contact-provider-button">
                        <td><a href="#" class="c-btn c-btn--red c-btn--small"
                               id="contact-form-button"
                               data-detail-route="{{ route('vendor.contact', ['en', $profile->user->id]) }}"
                               data-modal-open="contact-provider-form">@lang('profile.btnContact')</a>
                        </td>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-8/12">
            @if (isset($data) || !Route::is('vendor.edit'))
            <a href="#" data-modal-open="modal-report" class="c-link c-link__primary c-link--small js_modal-report"><span
                        data-icon="Q"></span> @lang('profile.vendorReportUser')</a>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="o-grid__col u-4/12 u-text-right">
            @if(!$profile->user->is_ahuser)
                <a href="#" data-modal-open="modal-imprint" class="c-link c-link__primary c-link--small">@lang('profile.vendorImprintLink')</a>
            @endif
        </div>

        @if($profile->user->is_ahuser)
            <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12 u-pt-x10">
                <p class="p2">@lang('profile.transferProfileText')
                    <a href="{{ route('registration.transferProfile', $profile->user->id) }}" class="c-link c-link__primary c-link--small">@lang('profile.transferProfileCTA')</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</section>
```

home-extended.blade.php

```
@extends ('layouts.profile-extended')

@push('inject-header-css')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/slider-custom.css') }}">

@endpush

@section ('inject-content')
  @php ($lang = app()->getLocale()) @endphp
  <main class="u-mt-x12">

    <!-- show detail modal-->
    @include('components.modals.search-detail')
    @include ('components.global.google-translate')

    @isset($page)
      <section class="o-container u-mb-x6">
        <div class="o-grid">
          @php
            $pageTitle =  $page->getTranslatedTitle(request('lang', $lang));
            $titleTranslate = 'notranslate';
            if (!(strlen($pageTitle) > 0)) {
                $titleTranslate = 'translate';
                $pageTitle = $page->getTranslatedTitle(request('lang', config('language.fallback')[$lang]));
            }
          @endphp
          <div class="o-grid__col u-12/12 {{$titleTranslate}}">
            @if(($page->category && $page->category->has_horses) || $page->slug === 'events')
              <div class="o-media o-media--res">
                <div class="o-media__fixed">
                  <h2>{{ $pageTitle }}</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="o-media__fluid u-text-right@md">
                  <button data-modal-open="modal-filter" id="filter-button"
                          class="c-btn c-btn--small c-btn--red">@lang('global.filterResults')
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            @else
              <h2>{{strip_tags($pageTitle)}}</h2>
            @endif
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      @if($page->category && $page->category->has_horses)
        <section class="o-container u-mb-x6 c-faq__container provider-search search-form-results"
                 data-url="{{ route('api.search') }}" id="page-horse-search"
                 data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-category-id="{{ $page->category->id }}" data-search-only="horse"
                 data-by-vendor="{{ $profile->id }}" data-target-container="horse-result">
          <div class="horse-result" id="horse-result">
            <span class="o-grid o-grid--equal-height results"></span>
          </div>
        </section>
        @include('components.modals.filter-horse')
      @endif

      @if($profile->has_events && $page->slug === 'events')
        <section class="o-container u-mb-x6 c-faq__container provider-search search-form-results"
                 data-url="{{ route('api.search') }}" id="page-event-search"
                 data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-search-only="event"
                 data-by-vendor="{{ $profile->id }}" data-target-container="event-result">
          <div class="event-result" id="event-result">
            <span class="o-grid o-grid--equal-height results"></span>
          </div>
        </section>
        @include('components.modals.filter-event')
      @endif

      <section class="o-container s-contentBlock">
        @foreach ($page->content_blocks as $block)
          @include($block->getView(), ['lang' => $lang, 'block' => $block])
        @endforeach
      </section>

    @endisset

    @include ('components.vendor.contact')
    @include ('components.global.banner.provider')
  </main>
@endsection

@push('inject-footer-scripts')
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/search-form/range-slider.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/provider-search.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/search-form/show-detail.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/provider/contact-provider.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    RangeSlider.sliderHelper.initRangeSliders();
  </script>
@endpush
```

in web.php the routing is done by:

```
Route::get('{urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/contact', 'VendorController@contact')
    ->name('vendor.contact');
```

contact-provider.js:

```
var ExtendedForm = ExtendedForm || {};

/**
 * Show search form modal with detailed info
 * @type {{init}}
 */
ExtendedForm.showSearchDetail = (function ($) {

  var _$container;
  var _$modal;

  var _clearAndShow = function () {
    $('.modal-content', _$modal).html('');
    _$modal.css({display: 'block'});
  };

  var _getContent = function (url) {
    $.get(url, function (res) {
      $('.modal-content', _$modal).html(res);
    });
  };

  /**
   * DOM ready inits
   * @private
   */
  var _init = function () {

    _$container = $('.contact-provider-button');
    _$modal = $('#contact-provider-form');

    $(function () {
      // click search result
      _$container.on('click', '#contact-form-button', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data('detail-route');
        $('body').addClass('u-overflow--hidden u-relative');
        _clearAndShow();
        _getContent(url);
      });

    });

  };

  return {
    init: _init
  }

})(jQuery);

ExtendedForm.showSearchDetail.init();
```

In VendorController I have a function contact:

```
public function contact(VendorProfile $vendor){
    return view(
        'components.profile.contact',
        ['profile' => $vendor, 'vendor' => $vendor->load('user.address')]
    );
}
```

server error log:

```
  [2019-02-26 08:14:34] local.ERROR: Route [vendor/contact] not defined. (View: /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/resources/views/components/vendor/contact.blade.php) (View: /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/resources/views/components/vendor/contact.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Route [vendor/contact] not defined. (View: /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/resources/views/components/vendor/contact.blade.php) (View: /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/resources/views/components/vendor/contact.blade.php) at /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:305, ErrorException(code: 0): Route [vendor/contact] not defined. (View: /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/resources/views/components/vendor/contact.blade.php) at /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:305, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Route [vendor/contact] not defined. at /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:305)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(45): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 0)
#1 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/stevenge...', Array)
#2 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(137): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('/Users/stevenge...', Array)
#3 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(120): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#4 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(85): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#5 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(42): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#6 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(206): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#7 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(724): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#8 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(698): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#9 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#10 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Middleware/Language.php(36): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\\Http\\Middleware\\Language->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/app/Http/Middleware/LanguageSetting.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\\Http\\Middleware\\LanguageSetting->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(68): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(660): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#39 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(65): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
```

.....
    #51 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #52 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
    #53 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
...
    #64 /Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/server.php(21): require_once('/Users/stevenge...')
    #65 {main}
    "}

route-list:

```
 GET|HEAD      | {urlLang}                                                                    | home                                 | Closure                                                                                | web                                                  |
|        | POST          | {urlLang}/cart/finalize                                                      | cart.finalize                        | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@finalize                                           | web,auth                                             |
|        | POST          | {urlLang}/cart/remove/{item}                                                 | cart.remove                          | App\Http\Controllers\CartController@remove                                             | web,auth                                             |
|        | GET|HEAD      | {urlLang}/category                                                           | category.index                                                              |                                      | App\Http\Controllers\ProReminderController@checkIfRemind                               | web                                                  |
|        | PUT|PATCH     | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}                                                    | vendor.update                        | App\Http\Controllers\VendorController@update                                           | web,auth,can:update,vendor                           |
|        | GET|HEAD      | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}                                                    | vendor.show                          | App\Http\Controllers\VendorController@show                                             | web                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD      | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/category/{category}/subpages                       | vendor.page.subpages                 | App\Http\Controllers\VendorPageController@subpages                                     | web,auth                                             |
|        | DELETE        | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/changes                                            | vendor.changes.destroy               | App\Http\Controllers\VendorChangesController@destroy                                   | web,auth,can:update,vendor                           |
|        | POST          | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/changes                                            | vendor.changes.store                 | App\Http\Controllers\VendorChangesController@store                                     | web,auth,can:update,vendor                           |
|        | GET|HEAD      | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/contact                                            | vendor.contact                       | App\Http\Controllers\VendorController@contact                                          | web                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD      | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/edit                                               | vendor.edit                          | App\Http\Controllers\VendorController@edit                                             | web,auth,can:update,vendor                           |
|        | POST          | {urlLang}/vendor/{vendor}/event                                              | vendor.event.store
```

I use a route-group for {urlLang}:

Route::view('/', 'welcome');

```
Route::get('{urlLang}', function () {
    $static = \App\StaticPage::where([
        'external_id' => 1,
        'lang' => app()->getLocale(),
    ])->first();
    return view('welcome', ['static'=>$static]);
})->name('home');
```

Comment: And what is the cause for the 500 error? Is there anything writen to your server's error log?

Comment: I add the log error in question

Comment: Where is your `Users/stevengerrits/ah-website/resources/views/components/vendor/contact.blade.php`?

Comment: Have you even **read** that error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase I first added the wrong one by mistake, this one I read yes

Comment: @vivek_23 what do you mean?

Comment: @belgiums show us your blade file. You have attached a route in your blade file that does not exist. Your current route in `routes/web.php` looks like `'vendor.contact'` and your error message says `Route [vendor/contact] not defined`.

Comment: @vivek_23 done :)

Comment: @belgiums Your route looks fine now. Do you get this error on visiting this URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/vendor/186/contact` or while loading the blade itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ route('vendor.contact', $profile->user->id) }}
```

Looks like your only passing one param into the laravel router. Your url requires two params one for `{urlLang}` and one for `{vendor}`

Try

```
{{ route('vendor.contact', ['en', $profile->user->id]) }}
```

Comment: then my route is "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/vendor/en/contact 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: So are you handing `/en/` in a `route::group` or something beforehand? Try adding a snippet of your `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I'm very new in Laravel, still learning the framework. Need to work on this project

Comment: added the route list

Comment: I have a route::group for urlLang:

Comment: I don't think, that urlLang is transferred to the route properly. Maybe you can dd(urlLang), so you know that it's set to 'en'.
Maybe you can develop the site first, before you put the Language in there.
Are you setting urlLang through a Middleware? Which one.

Comment: I added the middleware to the question

Comment: I would avoid localisation route prefixing unless its mission critical.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/en/vendor/en/contact

Comment: Yeah it setting correctly in your grouping, regardless of our suggestion. Your error exception is reporting `vendor/contact` but the named route is dot notation so should be `vendor.contact`.  Try replacing it with a full path url via `{{ url('/en/vendor/id/contact') }}` and see if it completes. Obv replace id with a user id.